# How share POJOs created by OpenAPI Generator in spring boot across micro-services?

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger, spring-rest, openapi-generator

Suppose I have 2 micro-services `Foo` and `Bar` and generate the POJOs using `gradle openApigenerate`  everything specified in yaml file.

The openAPI generator generates POJOs as follows:

```
Foo:
fooPojo1
fooPojo2
Accessible only to micro-service Foo
```

```
Bar:
barPojo1
barPojo2
Accessible only to micro-service Bar
```

Also I'm sharing models across both micro-service. So `barPojo1` and `barPojo2` is available in Foo and `fooPojo1` and `fooPojo2` is available in Bar.

However, if I want to use `fooPojo1` as a schema in `Bar` I need to re-declare `fooPojo1` in Bar micro-service which looks like:

```
Bar:
barPojo1
barPojo2
fooPojo1
```

So is there anyway I don't have to create repetitive objects and just reference the existing object from imported library something like:

```
Bar:
barPojo1
barPojo2
$ref: foo-service.fooPojo1
```

I need a solution for this because whenever I use `fooPojo1` in Bar service I need to map the `fooPojo1` of Bar service to `fooPojo1` of Foo service and vice-versa for internal comms.

I tried finding solution in OpenApi docs, stackoverflow and various other places, but not information. Not sure of referencing to external library works.

Comment: You can try to publish an API-JAR for the generated code in one project and consume it in the other.

Comment: @cyberbrain We already have a Jar published, but we also want the models in jar to be referenced to yaml, else we have to create a schema with same fields for request and response in the micro-service. If we could have some thing like
creditCard:
   jarPath: "foo-service.jar:CreditCardModel.java"

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with `schemaMappings`

Step 1: Add `Foo` as dependency in `Bar`

Step 2: Add

```
schemaMappings = ["FooPojo": "com.foo.pojo.FooPojo"]
```

to your openApi generator config.

Step 3:
Create an empty schema in your yaml file with the same name

```
FooPojo:
   type: object
```

Step 4:

Reference it in `Bar`

```
BarPojo:
   type: object
   properties:
      fooPojo:
        $ref: '#/components/schemas/FooPojo'
```